# Windows 10 taskbar is not responding when USB Switch device is plugged when system starts

Tags: windows-10, usb, freeze, taskbar

**What is the problem**
Windows taskbar freezes (infinite loading cursor) when USB Switch is plugged in while turning on the PC. I've checked this USB port with other devices and the error does not occur for them.

Answer (score 0):

When a machine (PC or other device) boots or when a USB device is plugged into the PC, the device has to identify itself to the PC by *type*, e.g., flash storage, hub, keyboard or printer. It might be that the PC cannot *natively* handle type *USB Switch*, and is looking for a driver (which *would* be available after the OS has booted).

It could also be that the USB identification is faulty, [or even contains malware](https://www.gdatasoftware.com/blog/2021/11/usb-drives-still-a-danger)! For example, a USB mouse might intentionally misidentify itself as a mouse *and* keyboard, and then through embedded code "type" on the keyboard to execute malicious code. This is not a *likely* scenario, though, more for targeted attack.

Comment: Thank you for your quick and an extended response! Could you please then provide me some details how can I investigate this thing?

Comment: There's not much one can do without forensic software and *hardware* to check if the USB has malware; but I believe the more likely issue is that the drivers are not active until the PC boots. It doesn't solve the issue, just means that every time you perform a *full* shutdown, also unplug the switch.

Comment: Yeah I guess I will have to live with that. However thank you for the clues.